# ServerSocketChannel.accept() vs ServerSocket.accept()

Tags: java, sockets, nio

If I configure the ServerSocketChannel as non-blocking, then is there any difference between calling

ServerSocketChannel.accept().socket() and ServerSocket.accept() ?

from below

```
ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
ssc.configureBlocking( false );
ServerSocket ss = ssc.socket();
InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress( port );
ss.bind( isa );

Selector selector = Selector.open(); 
ssc.register( selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT ); 
System.out.println( "Listening on port "+port );
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( 4096 );

while (true) {

int numKeys = selector.select();
if (numKeys>0) {
 Set skeys = selector.selectedKeys();
Iterator it = skeys.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {

  SelectionKey rsk = (SelectionKey)it.next();
  int rskOps = rsk.readyOps();

  if ((rskOps & SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) ==
      SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) {

    Socket socket = ss.accept()  

   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered consulting the Javadoc?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that one returns a `SocketChannel` and the other a `Socket`.

As you are presumably going to select on the result, there really isn't any point in using `SsrverSocket.accept()`, as you would only have to get the `SocketChannel` from it anyway, put it into non-blocking mode, register it with the `Selector`, and do all the I/O with it, making little or no further use of the `Socket`.

Comment: I wanted difference between ServerSocketChannel.accept().socket() and ServerSocket.accept() . ServerSocketChannel.accept().socket()  returns socket as well as ServerSocket.accept().

Comment: @Pushparaj It is as I stated. See the Javadoc.